# Webworker import fails to resolve

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to tweak this component: https://github.com/Lucas-C/Nonogram

I added the src folder to my project. When using Game and Editor classes, no problem arise. When I try to import Solver class, however, I get an error:

```
@parcel/core: Failed to resolve 'worker!./worker.ts’ from from './nonogram_lib/Solver.ts’
```

It looks like this import fails. How can I fix that?

```
import SolverWorker from 'worker!./worker.ts'
```

My package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "parcel": "^2.8.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "^4.6.4"
  },
```

My tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noEmit": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "es6"
  }
}
```

Comment: Looks like the [definition file](https://github.com/Lucas-C/Nonogram/blob/976c3fad89fbb5d0b15c18a1396588d6d93e4087/src/global.d.ts#L37) is not picked up correctly. I don't really see the reason why this should not be imported like `import SolverWorker from './worker.ts'` though?

Comment: It is hard to diagnose your issue with the info given. _HOWEVER,_ it looks like the referenced repo is using a [rollup plugin](https://github.com/Lucas-C/Nonogram/blob/976c3fad89fbb5d0b15c18a1396588d6d93e4087/rollup.config.js#L13) ([plugin repo](https://github.com/darionco/rollup-plugin-web-worker-loader)) that turns the contents of the worker file into an importable class. You're using parcel rather than rollup. Consider either a.) switching to rollup/vite or b.) doing a classic worker instantiation (`new Worker('./worker.ts');`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line in `Solver.ts` causes problem.

```
import SolverWorker from 'worker!./worker.ts'

export default class Solver extends Nonogram {
  worker: Worker = new SolverWorker()
// ...
```

Like @webelo pointed out in comment, the `worker!` prefix is a rollup plugin hint, if you check the original repo uses [`rollup-plugin-bundle-worker`](https://github.com/andyearnshaw/rollup-plugin-bundle-worker).

Because you use parcel as bundler, you need to convert it into parcel's way of importing a worker, which should be:

```
export default class Solver extends Nonogram {
  worker: Worker = new Worker(
    new URL('worker.ts', import.meta.url),
    {type: 'module'}
  );
```

Worth noting that, [`new URL('worker.ts', import.meta.url)`](https://parceljs.org/languages/javascript/#url-dependencies) and [`new Worker(...)`](https://parceljs.org/languages/javascript/#workers), even though both are web standard APIs, they actually have some parcel magic mixed-in behind the scene. Check the link for details.